# Restrict geocode from GoogleMaps API to a city?

Tags: python, google-maps-api-3

I have a list of addresses that are street names in a US city. I want to turn them into GoogleV3 location objects. I seem to have trouble restricting to a city, and can't find any solid examples of how to go about doing so in Python.

For example, Columbus Avenue is in Derwood, MD. However the following line of code:

```
from geopy import geocoders
from geopy.geocoders import GoogleV3
gmaps = GoogleV3(api_key=MY_KEY)
gmaps.geocode('Columbus Avenue', components = {'country':'US','postal_code_prefix':'20','region':'MD'}, timeout=15)
```

returns

```
Location(9th Ave, New York, NY, USA, (40.76921230000001, -73.9847724, 0.0))
```

How can I restrict the geocode command to search only for places near to Derwood?

Answer (score 0):

It seemed to work by simply appending 'Derwood MD, USA' to the string 'Columbus Avenue'. I don't know how useful the components options were.